# Error in install R package "RColorBrewer"

Tags: r, linux, centos, rstudio-server, libv8

i try to :

```
> install.packages("randomcoloR")
......
Error in curl::curl_download("https://github.com/jeroen/V8/releases/download/v3.6.0/v8-9.6.180.12-amd64.tar.gz",  : 
  Timeout was reached: [] Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
Execution halted
tar (child): libv8.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
......
```

so i try to :

```
> curl::curl_download("https://github.com/jeroen/V8/releases/download/v3.6.0/v8-9.6.180.12-amd64.tar.gz")
```

and i get :

```
 Error in normalizePath(destfile, mustWork = FALSE) : 
      argument "destfile" is missing, with no default
```

so,what should i do?

Comment: i used :
devtools::install_github("jeroen/V8")
and got the same error

Comment: Your title says RColorBrewer but your code looks like you are working with randomcoloR. So is RColorBrewer actually involved here at all?

Comment: The [V8 Github page](https://github.com/jeroen/V8/) says under "installation" *"On Linux you need a suitable `libv8` installation, see below."* and then offers a few steps. Have you done those steps? Some are CentOS-specific.

Comment: And the `curl::download` argument is pretty clear - it requires at least 2 arguments, (1) the URL, which you have, and (2) `destfile` where you want to save the file, which you don't have.

Comment: oh，sorry，I wrote the wrong title.

Comment: i used  V8 Github page : `Sys.setenv(DOWNLOAD_STATIC_LIBV8 = 1)
install.packages("V8")`  and  return `Error in curl::curl_download("https://github.com/jeroen/V8/releases/download/v3.6.0/v8-9.6.180.12-amd64.tar.gz",  : 
  Empty reply from server`

Comment: I think it's possible that my network could not connect to Github